# regex match string that does not contain substr and case insensitive

Tags: regex

I have a a string like maxreheattemp.  I want my regex test to fail when the substring reheat is in it.  I can do that with

```
^((?!reheat).)*$
```

but I also want my test to be case insensitive.  I usually use (?i) for that, but can't find a way to combine the two so that maxReHeattemp also fails.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With PCRE engine, you can do:

```
^(?i)((?!reheat).)*$
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/gZ18zV/1)

Comment: It seems the OP has already tried that?

Comment: @Glorfindel: True, but I presume he doesn't use it the right way.

Comment: Yes that works. I guess my deployed environment uses a different regex engine than my test one.  Thanks.